# How to integrate an existing Angular 5 project with Apostrophe CMS?

Tags: javascript, angular, content-management-system, angular5, apostrophe-cms

I a have an Angular 5 project up and running, and I would like to add a CMS to allow admin control over content.

I would like to use something that works with NodeJS, ApostropheCMS state that any front-end application can integrate with their technology, but I can't find anything to help me understand how this is done.

I am Looking for help to understand the integration process, if possible at all !?
And if it isn't then what would be alternative solution considering the Angular 5 project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using the [apostrophe-headless](https://npmjs.org/package/apostrophe-headless) module. In that configuration you could build a separate backend site just for editing the content and use the headless APIs from your angular site so you don't have to deal with any disagreements between them over frontend things.

Comment: From what I can see, any headless CMS loses its' point since it only serves as a webapi, hence we lost the front management. Is there any CMS that can be give a front-end project as input, and parse/compile its' DOM tree into a somewhat ready to work front-end CMS?

Comment: OK, so what you want is in-context editing within an Angular-powered UI. That's not something that exists right now in Apostrophe. It would make a great contribution though.

Comment: I've already integrated Umbraco into doing this, since demands don't really justify time to spend on building this....I guess at this point there is no easy to use plugin for this